# Fabric's connection.forward_local fails when going out of scope

Tags: python, ssh, fabric

I'm trying to get a python script to enable port forwarding from a remote host to the local machine to access an interface.

If I do it manually with
`ssh -L 54321:someotherhost:80 user@host` (with password prompt) this works just fine and I can access the interface on `http://localhost:54321/someinterface` just as expected.

Now I'm trying to do it with fabric:

```py
from fabric import Connection

HOST = "somehost"
USER = "someuser"
PASSWORD = "somepassword"
LOCAL_PORT = "54321"
REMOTE_PORT = "80"
REMOTE_HOST = "someotherhost"

kwargs = {
    "password": PASSWORD
}
with Connection(HOST, user=USER, connect_kwargs=kwargs).forward_local(
        LOCAL_PORT, REMOTE_PORT, REMOTE_HOST, "localhost"
):
    pass # access interface e.g. via the requests package
```

However, 1.) the forwarding doesn't seem to work, reasons unknown and 2.) when the last line within the scope of `forward_local` is executed, it stops with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\path\to\script.py", line 67, in <module>
    main()
  File ".\path\to\script.py", line 35, in main
    pass
  File "C:\Users\ott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\contextlib.py", line 119, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\ott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\fabric\connection.py", line 883, in forward_local
    raise ThreadException([wrapper])
invoke.exceptions.ThreadException: 
Saw 1 exceptions within threads (TypeError):

Thread args: {}

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\ott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\invoke\util.py", line 231, in run
    self._run()

  File "C:\Users\ott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\fabric\tunnels.py", line 60, in _run
    sock.bind(self.local_address)

TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

It's possible 1.) and 2.) are related, but I'm focusing on 2.) right now. It doesn't matter what I do within the scope of the context manager produced by `forward_local`, on the last executed statement it stops. I presume this is caused by something when the context manager is closed by python when the interpreter leaves the scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.fabfile.org/en/2.5/api/connection.html) parameters like:

- local_port
- remote_port

have to be integers not string. That's why you got:

> TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

So, changing variables:

```
LOCAL_PORT = "54321"
REMOTE_PORT = "80"
```

to

```
LOCAL_PORT = 54321
REMOTE_PORT = 80
```

should fix the problem.